# PostGIS spatial join with many conditions

Tags: postgis, spatial-join

p1 Table:

| geom | lic_li_no | descriptor | attribute1 | attribute 2 | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4326 | 123456 | LSD-xx SEC-xx TWP-xxx RGE-xx MER-x | state 1 | state2 | stateN |

p2 Table:

| geom | lic_li_no | orig_licli | descriptor | ra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4326 | 123456 | 11155 | LSD-xx SEC-xx TWP-xxx RGE-xx MER-x | null/not null |

I have two point tables and would like to join the attributes from P1 (hexagons) to P2 (red diamonds) via various combinations of attribute values/spatial conditions.

How do I join these tables multiple times under various join conditions?

An illustration of the various scenarios is shown below.  Note: There are many P2 points (red diamonds) because they represent midpoints of each line within the descriptor polygon (intersected lines), however, I omitted all of them for clarity and only illustrate the target locations for joining.

The final table I would like to produce is one that has all the attributes from the associated hexagons (P1 points) joined to their corresponding P2 points, and if they can't be joined then they should keep the same geom.

The different join scenarios and conditions I have are as follows:

1. p1.lic_li_no = p2.lic_li_no
   AND
   p1.descriptor = p2.descriptor
2. p1.lic_li_no = p2.orig_licli
   AND
   p1.descriptor = p2.descriptor
3. p1.lic_li_no = p2.lic_li_no
   AND
   p1.descriptor != p2.descriptor
   AND
   p2.ra IS NOT NULL
   AND choose closest p2 point by knn
4. p1.lic_li_no = p2.orig_licli
   AND
   p1.descriptor != p2.descriptor
   AND
   p2.ra IS NOT NULL
   AND choose closest p2 point by knn
5. p1.lic_li_no = p2.lic_li_no
   AND
   p1.descriptor != p2.descriptor
   AND
   p2.ra IS NULL
   AND St_DWithin(descriptor polygon, 5)
6. p1.lic_li_no = p2.orig_licli
   AND
   p1.descriptor != p2.descriptor
   AND
   p2.ra IS NULL
   AND St_DWithin(descriptor polygon, 5)

[image]

Comment: You don't have a question in the Question body.

Comment: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/joins.html

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Alias each table as a different name, join it multiple times: `select a.blah, b.blah, c.blah from lic_1 a join lic_1 b on a.id = b.id join lic_1 c on st_intersects(a.geom,c.geom)` etc.